# Open iTunes with current track via my application

Tags: xcode, itunes, itunes-search-api

please help with my problem. I have mobile application of some radiostation. I use AVPlayer for playing music and get metadata, so i need to make search current track or artist(metadata) via iTunes app. I can not find any really important information about search music via my app to iTunes.(I don't want to use JSON from Apple)

So i use this code, it's very simple code but how i am understand iTunes search any information about current artist by this number 17976294 not name artist or name track:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/fr/artist/armin/17976294"]];
}
```

So maybe you have the same situation, please how to solve my problem.
[image]

UPS: So how i am understand it very-very easy, just use direct link (http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=25) and parse keys which we need.

Comment: "I don't want to use JSON from Apple" So you completely rule out doing this the right way?

Comment: @matt no-no i try to find another way without JSON..